# Reset variable at each iteration of PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, while-loop

I'm essentially using a foreach loop to loop through some post categories and then output some markup for the posts in each category. I thought my variable $ii would get reset at each iteration of the foreach, but it caries over (silly assumption on my part).  I do need $ii=1 at the beginning of each loop, is there a way to accomplish this? Basic code structure below

```
$cats = array(
    'cat1' => 20,
    'cat2' => 21,
    'cat3' => 22,
    'cat4' => 23
);

foreach($cats as $cat){
    $ii = 1;
    $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat);


    echo "<div class='container'>
            <h1>$cat_name</h1>
        ";
        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $title = get_the_title() . ' ' . $ii;

            if( in_category($cat) ){
                echo "<p>$title</p>";
            }

        $ii++; endwhile;
    echo '</div>'; // end container
}
```

For three posts in each category, what's being outputted is, essentially:

```
Cat1
- title 1
- title 2
- title 3
Cat2
- title 4
- title 5
- title 6

etc.
```

My desired output is:

```
Cat1
- title 1
- title 2
- title 3
Cat2
- title 1
- title 2
- title 3
```

Is there a way to reset the variable for each iteration to achieve my desired output? Or a better way to do this? Haven't been able to find anything on it yet. Seems pretty simple, though. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: 
A bunch of the answers on here got something working, but scoping the counter to a condition helped me solve the issues I needed. Kind of a workaround, but I basically just needed to check if I was on the 5th iteration of the while loop in a specific category to output a certain block of markup for a  special case. (Sorry if the way I posed the question left my objective a little bit ambiguous, there's a lot going on in the actual loops I'm running - I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.) So, as of now, the workaround looks like so:

```
if( $cat == $cats['cat2']){
    $ii++;
    if($ii === 5){
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Still feel like there's a more robust way of accomplishing this and I'm open to new ideas for it, but it's working for now!

Comment: Put `$ii = 0;` before your `foreach(){}` loop and then just use `$title = get_the_title() . ' ' . ++$ii;`. Get rid of all other uses of `$ii`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's going on inside those functions of yours but try building your `$title` variable inside your `in_category()` condition check

```
if (in_category($cat)) {
    $title = get_the_title() . ' ' . $ii;
    echo "<p>$title</p>";
    $ii++;
}
```

It looks like your functions for grabbing posts are re-grabbing every post again and only outputting the ones you need based on the value of $cat, via `in_category()`. Your $ii counter should be resetting just fine since you are explicitly setting it to 1 at the beginning of each foreach iteration.

Comment: I had the same assumption about the counter resetting, but it didn't behave that way! However, scoping the incrementation to the category I needed to do it in worked for me. Sorry if the question was framed a little ambiguously, but thanks for giving me a push in the right direction! :)

Comment: It is resetting but you are incrementing $ii *eventhough* you are not inside the right category. That's why your output would skip the first 3 and show 4, 5, 6 on the second category. If $ii wasn't resetting back to 1, your second category would show 7, 8, 9

Answer (score 0):

You could increment a different counter inside the while loop then increment the other counter after the while loop ends:

```
$counter = 1;
while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        $title = get_the_title() . ' ' . $counter;

        if( in_category($cat) ){
            echo "<p>$title</p>";
        }

        $counter++;

endwhile;

$ii++;
```